# Bad answer → Downvote → Edit within 5 mins → Undo → Vote locked in

Tags: bug, voting, down-votes, locked-votes, undo

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17502408/1563422) gave a reason why the OP's code wasn't working, but didn't provide any alternative code; I downvoted it. Then the OP edited it to include some code, but my vote is still locked in:

> [image]

(The last line of code wasn't there when I downvoted).

I've edited the answer now, to bypass the lock, but this is a bug that should be fixed.

Comment: @ben possibly not a duplicate - the message seems to indicate that it should be possible to reverse the vote because the Q was edited, but it wasn't? So either the message is wrong or the feature is buggy?

Comment: @slugster The feature is buggy, but it's still a duplicate. I've voted to close myself too `:p`

Comment: They're both about votes being locked in when a question is edited during the grace period @slugster (and the OP seems to agree).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Are you able to see who has voted to close, before it gets 5 votes?

Comment: No @Danny, I inferred you agreed by your editing and commenting on the other question. I didn't know whether you voted to close or not.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks @benisuǝqbackwards!

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62219/cannot-retract-downvote-if-post-has-been-edited-within-first-5-minutes-of-postin