# 5-minute window for undownvoting

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Most of the time, if I want to undownvote, it's because I come to understand the question differently or realized a misunderstanding of the answer. These things often happen long after the 5-minute window.

I realize the system is working as designed, but should it have more leeway? It only happens to me occasionally but it does happen. I have high rep, I cast a lot of votes, shit happens. The result is obnoxious to the answerer.

See also [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38759/143172) from 2009 when the limitation was implemented.

Comment: Is this a feature request? This seems like one.

Comment: `I cast a lot of votes, $#@* happens.` -- Maybe pause for a moment before voting?

Comment: @Potatoswatter Considering this is actually intended to prompt discussion rather than suggest something, I've edited your question slightly to make it a more direct question.