# How can we correctly deal with downvoted edited questions?

Tags: discussion, edits, voting, down-votes

Let's say a question is asked, which receives a few downvotes and suggestions that a question should be improved, then closed. The question is later edited by the OP, addressing some of the issues, with a request for reopening. The request is satisfied, and the question is reopened for further answers. Is it correct to assume that it is the responsibility of the users that have issued the downvotes to check the question and potentially change their vote, if the edit changes their evaluation?

If yes, do they actually do it in practice? What is the right way to act, both when asking such a question, and when deciding to downvote somebody else's question?

Comment: No, users have no obligation what so ever to check back. If a certain user commented the question, you can reply to them to ask if your edit satisfied their request. That would be the way to get their attention.

Comment: *Vote and move on* is the general idea. If a post is improved that much that it warrants other votes then downvotes, those other votes will happen over time.

Comment: @rene So basically if I see a question that I deem below standard, I should downvote it without considering that the user may improve it in the future, and leave it to future readers to upvote it if they choose to do so? Is this written officially somewhere, or more a rule of thumb?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote and [Vote early and often](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/19/vote-early-vote-often/)

Comment: Before anyone suggests those down voters should be notified of a change to a contribution they have not followed, keep it mind, the best way to avoid downvotes is to submit the high quality contribution initially instead of the suboptimal question. Some users review dozens of questions a day, voting accordingly, to help with the quality of the contributions.  That’s far to many contributions to follow when most will never be improved (for many reasons)

Answer (score 10):

> What is the right way to act, both when asking such a question

The right way is ... not ask such a question in the first place. Writing good questions can be hard, we know, but with the guidance provided by the system and the community, and enough effort on the asker's part, it is within all users' reach to write a decent question.

> and when deciding to downvote somebody else's question

If you think the question might be edited into better shape, you can [follow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/295232) it, so you'll be notified of any edits. The edit also causes the [vote lock-in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23701/295232) to be lifted, so you can undo your downvote, and even upvote if the question warrants it.

Comment: I agree with the 2nd part. The first part of your answer misses the point I think. I do not argue against asking good questions. I argue that many people will ask subpotimal questions from time to time even when investing a reasonable amount of effort not to do so. The question is about dealing with exceptional situations, not about maintaining the main function

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does a new user avail themselves of all the guidance the community might provide without actually writing a question that starts out bad enough to garner a few down votes? “Just write good questions” seems unhelpful in this context, and I’m sure that’s not what you intended.

Comment: Yeah, there's a difference between *good* questions and decent questions (questions that deserve neither upvotes nor downvotes). You don't need all the guidance at once, I often see users who fail to "Include all the information someone would need to answer your question" (from [Ask a question](/questions/ask)).

Comment: We all know many new users with a burning question don’t know that they need to read the guidance on how to ask a question because SE is so different from other sites. Every meta probably has multiple discussions on low quality questions and educating new users. “Don’t ask questions that someone might downvote” isn’t helpful advice when someone is asking about how to go about salvaging a question that’s been downvoted. I doubt someone asking a question on parenting would find answers starting with “Well, you shouldn’t have had a kid if you weren’t going to be a good parent…” helpful.