# How do I undo an accidental undo of an up vote?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, locked, undo

I accidentally undid my upvote on a question thinking I was upvoting it, but it undid my upvote, so I click again to re-upvote it, but it is locked unless the question is edited.

I can post a comment asked the submitter to edit their question so that I can re-upvote it, but that seems rather round-about.

Is there a better way to do this?

If not, shouldn't an 'up undo up' pattern be allowed if in a short period of time?  You can undo your up vote if it is a mistake, why not undo your undo if it was a mistake?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19021/request-change-in-behaviour-vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited