# Cannot undo my vote. Should I edit the answer myself to unlock voting?

Tags: support

I upvoted two answers (one on supersuser, the other on askubuntu), and downvoted other answers that said the contrary about the subject.

However, while experimenting, I found out that I was completely wrong, as were the answers that I upvoted.

I came back to undo my votes, but was too late; the 1 hour limit was reached.

Should I edit the answer myself to unlock my vote?
Is there a more legitimate option?

Comment: You're doomed..

Comment: The lesson: You should experiment before you vote.

Comment: Be righter sooner.

Comment: related for meta sites: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171694/dont-lock-votes-on-meta-sites

Answer (score 1):

Don't edit to remove your vote. Edit to improve the post. Removing your vote is a bonus.

An edit should always introduce some sort of significant improvement to the question. Don't edit needlessly just to bump or change a vote. Always have a substantial reason.

Comment: [If It's good enough for Jeff Atwood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19021/request-change-in-behaviour-vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited/19022#comment41494_19022) than It should be good enough for us right?

Comment: @SamIam: By that approach, [we are also a forum](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/503/do-we-need-unicode-tag-support#comment990_504). I don't like taking random lines that people said over the years and force them to be canon. Edit exists for a reason, changing your vote isn't that reason, it's a bonus. Don't treat it as such, please. Also with all due respect, Jeff Atwood is not perfect, none of us are. What's good enough for him, isn't what's good enough for the rest of the site, sometimes.

Comment: @SamIam: Jeff Atwood isn't with SE anymore either.