# Upvote downvoted answer

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vote too old to be changed, unless post is edited “problem”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited-problem)

By mistake I downvoted good answer that was upvoted by me earlier. Now I cannot upvote it again because the answer is too old. I asked answer author to edit his answer and then was able to upvote it again.

Is there other way to repair such mistake?

I think SO should allow me to change my decision within some time, but maybe I omitted something.

Comment: Hi.  Questions about stackoverflow belong at http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I've seen this problem too. This should be moved to meta and hopefully the SO development team will do something with it.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited-problem

Answer (score 1):

It's designed to prevent people gaming the system - particularly downvoting other answers on questions they've upvoted. See this [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited-problem).