# Why can't I recast a vote?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vote too old to be changed, unless post is edited “problem”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited-problem)

Try this:

1. Find an incorrect answer (this step requires reading the question @random)
2. Down-vote it.
3. Reread the question, and decide to remove your downvote.
4. Wait 5 or so minutes
5. Reread the incorrect answer, and re-decide to down-vote it (it currently doesn't have a vote assigned by you. **this is important**).

You will be told that you can't change your vote unless the question is edited.

The simplest solution would be for me to make up my mind and either cast the down-vote or not, but I still think this is a bug.

Was this intentional?

**EDIT:**

Alright, I didn't make the issue clear.  I understand that I shouldn't be allowed to change a vote if I have left a +1 or a -1 vote.  But when you give a -1 then take it back you can't go back and reissue the vote after a period of time.

**When I go back and try to issue a vote to a question that has neither a +1 nor a -1, I am told I can't vote.**

This is different from the other posts that say: *When I try to remove a vote or change my vote to a question/answer that I have **already voted** on I can't **change** my vote.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited-problem

Comment: This is quickly becoming the most reported bug on MSO. **This is not a bug**

Comment: Why down vote (or upvote) *before* you even **read** the post?

Comment: Hey, Diago, come on, the last one was closed at least two hours ago.

Comment: I added some jest to the instructions...which unfortunately disguised the issue I was trying to address.

Comment: It's the same thing. You've already voted on the question. Even if that vote was to unvote, that still counts as an actual vote.

Comment: Alright, fair enough.