# Locking the votes

Tags: feature-request, bug, voting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the justification for locking votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70853/what-is-the-justification-for-locking-votes)
>   [Why can't I recast a vote (possible bug)?[edited]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27052/why-cant-i-recast-a-vote-possible-bugedited)

I just found that one can cast a vote, change their mind and uncast the vote. The vote gets locked and it is not possible to cast a vote later on.

Is this as intended? If yes, why?

Comment: @ChrisF Not really. There he casted a vote, and I casted and uncasted right away. My cast didn't take place and I could not cast later on

Comment: I just tried it on  @Chris answer to the other question and it worked just fine: I upvoted, clicked again to undo then cast upvote again and it worked. Unless by "later on" you mean after the timeout?

Comment: @VJo - even if you cancel your vote straight away the system still registers that you "voted". So if you try again after the time out (5 minutes) you **will** be locked out.

Comment: @shadow, yes after the timeout.  Steps: 1. Cast a vote and then cancel it.  2. Come back more than 5 minutes or so later, try to cast a vote but you are locked out.

Comment: @Vjo the answers are the same, though.

Comment: @VJo so what you ask is actually feature request, not a bug. IMO good feature request, as undoing the vote right away (e.g. within 5 seconds) means you done it by mistake..

Comment: It really is a bug, even if it is broken by design.  I am not "changing" my vote, I am choosing to vote.

Comment: @Tim The answers are same due to a bug, or why?

Comment: @Vjo The answer in the other question explain the justification for locking votes. If I read your question correctly, this is what you are asking for.

Comment: @Tim I understand why the locked vote is not allowed to be modified. But if the cast is reverted within allowed time, and the vote is locked out, that sounds like a bug.

Comment: @Shog9 You are right. It is a duplicate. But I don't see of what is that question duplicate of.

Comment: @VJo: they're all (and there are *scores* of these questions, because it's not at all obvious) related to the same, um, feature: voting changes are time-limited, and "undoing" a vote doesn't reset that timer. As for *why* it works this way, see the question ChrisF linked to above.