# Upvote/Downvote lock should happen only if upvoted/downvoted

Tags: discussion, support, voting

Recently there was a new feature introduced in the SE sites where your upvotes/downvotes are locked after few minutes. you will not be able to upvote/downvote the same question or answer after that specified time unless the user edits his question or answer.

However, there are cases when I just downvote and then cancel my downvote immediately and leave the decision for future. Sometime later I visit the same question or answer and try to upvote but I am not allowed to do so since my voting is locked for that particular question or answer.

My question is, should the locking should happen only if I have upvoted or downvoted and not when I cancel my votes? Or should it be the way it is now?

Comment: s/recently/in 2009/

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27052/why-cant-i-recast-a-vote-possible-bugedited

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vote too old to be changed, unless post is edited "problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited-problem)