# Can not upvote a particular answer after undoing an upvote

Tags: bug, voting, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vote too old to be changed, unless post is edited “problem”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited-problem)

I am trying to upvote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401225/template-classes-and-include-guards-in-c/2401253#2401253), but it is saying that the vote is too old to be changed even though I had not voted.

I actually accidentally clicked on upvote for this once then immediately clicked it on again to undo it.

Now, I actually want to upvote it but it is not allowing me.

Comment: Even though it was an accident and you revoked it straight away it counts as voting and sets the timer. It might be nicer if undoing a vote (as opposed to voting the other way) within 30 seconds (say) cleared the fact that you'd voted. Any longer and it wasn't an accident that you'd voted.

Comment: 30 seconds can be enough to turn the tide on a high traffic/view question for it to be an exploit of perception. @chr

Comment: @random - OK, how about a 10 second limit or even a 5 second one?

Comment: I really don't think it's a duplicate, this one is not about voting and then being unable to change the vote, but voting and undoing, maybe related, but not a dupe imo

Comment: I don't agree that it is a duplicate of the linked question. I understand why "vote too old to be changed" is required. But here, it allowed me to undo my vote which means that I still have chance for voting. Otherwise, undo shouldn't have been allowed in the first place.

Comment: I voted to re-open (I think for the first time)

Answer (score 0):

It has happened to me, my guess is that voting and undoing counts as a vote, and then you can't "change your vote" until it's edited.

I don't know if it's a bug or a feature though

Comment: It's a feature insofar that Jeff would have to admit that he is wrong about it in order to fix it. Because Jeff is incapable of admitting one of his ideas is so obviously user-unfriendly this bug will forever go unfixed.

Comment: @NIfE it's not "my idea" it's "we have to do this otherwise tactical downvoting can be used to influence answers". Sorry.

Comment: I'm on to you, Jeff.