# After cancelling upvote, can't re-upvote answer

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vote too old to be changed, unless post is edited “problem”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited-problem)

I clicked "upvote" on the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731656/how-to-style-html-to-display-2-data-cards-to-a-printed-page).

Then I cancelled the upvote a few seconds later. A few hours later, I chose that answer as the correct one, and wanted to upvote it again, but now I get the message "You last voted on this answer 16 hours ago Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited".

Shouldn't I be able to upvote it now, since I cancelled my original upvote a long time ago?

Comment: I don't believe it's a duplicate, because there is no vote! I am now unable to upvote the answer, because at one point I upvoted then cancelled it. :(

Comment: it's a little complicated. There are other dupes that more closely match yours, but they are closed as dupes of the one I linked to. The bottom line is that this is `[status-bydesign]`. Undoing a vote counts as a vote - hence you can't vote again later. I don't like it, but that's how they want it to work.

Comment: Here's a better match for a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41498/can-not-upvote-a-particular-answer-after-undoing-an-upvote

Comment: You *should* be able to upvote, but Jeff has some trouble with common sense. Therefore you are not able to do it. No, you do not have to understand that. If you are not able to edit the post, ask the poster to do it for you (comments for the rescue).

Comment: @ladybug I have *trouble* with the exploits around allowing vote undo..