# Why is Re-Up Voting on Cancelled Up Vote Not Allowed?

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Vote too old to be changed, unless post is edited “problem”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited-problem)
>   [After cancelling upvote, can't re-upvote answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64884/after-cancelling-upvote-cant-re-upvote-answer)

Why is re-up-voting on a canceled previous up-vote disallowed?  For example, if I up-vote a question, then cancel my up-vote by clicking the up-ticker again, and later (after more research, say 22 minutes later) decided to re-up-vote the question, it tells me that I cannot change my vote, unless the question is changed.  I can't change a non-vote?  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Duplicated a thousand times, Jeff has stated he will not fix this obvious user-model vs system-model usability issue because he hates users and wants them to be reminded of it on a nearly daily basis, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited-problem, blah blah blah +1

Comment: @Sid - I have never agreed with anything as much as I agree with what you just said. +∞

Comment: @Jon: You're a liar because I've said what I just said many times before. By definition you've agreed with me every time.

Comment: @Sid - you're a liar because I don't recall reading anything by you that said any such thing. And I've read everything you've even written. And I remember everything.

Comment: @Jon: Do you remember how many breads you've eaten in your life?

Comment: @Sid - if by "breads" you mean an entire loaf, and if by "eaten" you mean in one sitting: zero. Excluding very small loafs. But that would be silly to count those.

Comment: @Jon: You need to know more of the same Internet memes that I do so that you don't end up embarassing yourself when you reply to me like this.

Comment: @Sid - now you owe me a link. And it better be funny.

Comment: @Jon: Too lazy.

Comment: And, that is what a philosophical debate between programmers looks like, ladies and gentlemen.