# I can not upvote to the answer

Tags: support, answers, up-votes, users

I have accepted one anwer and I had given one up vote to the answer and again tried to give one more upvote then the vote count was decreemented to the answer and now I can not upvote the anwer like there is one vote already then I upvoted to the answer then vote count to the answer was 2 then I again tried to upvote then vote count was then 1 again and now it canno be upvoted by me,then what is the problem can not I now able to upvote the answer now onwards and other question is can not I give the two upvotes to one answer ?

Error comes like :
Vote too old to be changed, unless this answer is edited
(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: is that a riddle?

Comment: @Nick D: I think it's one of those cryptic riddles that doesn't have an actual answer, but prompts you to reconsider your own psyche.

Comment: I guess that meets the "describe your problem in one sentence" rule.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is normal. When you tried to add a second vote you actually *removed* the first vote. Now you can't re-upvote due to the "vote too old to be changed" rule. If you post a link to the answer, one of us will edit it for you so you can re-upvote it.

Comment: Thank You...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566322/string-matching

Comment: @Hari - there you go - you should be able to upvote now.