# incidental votes can occur when using touch devices

Tags: feature-request, voting, locked-votes

​When I am scrolling answers on my iPad, my taps are sometimes considered as votes. Usually I notice it immediately and undo it, but a couple times I've noticed it too late and my vote was already locked.

The other way to accidentally vote is just to keep iPad (or iPhone) in hand and unintentionally press by left hand thumb on vote arrow.

The site has an easy ability to vote( and it's good) and so hard to undo the vote after 5 min( and it is not good)

​With an increased number of touch devices (e.g. iPad, iPhone and other smartphones/tablets), it's one more reason to remove the time lock for votes - see related [What is the justification for locking votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70853/what-is-the-justification-for-locking-votes/) and [Vote too old to be changed, unless post is edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited/)

Comment: Never had an issue on Galaxy's 4.3" screen (I'm browsing the full site, not the mobile version). Can't imagine this happening on the iPad, perhaps you have exceptionally fat fingers?

Comment: It's not about the size of the fingers. The problem if the Scrolling gesture over the vote arrows is considered as tap.

Comment: It was more of a [pun](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fat-finger) than an actual comment on the size of your fingers ;) The point being, that I think this is a bit localized, I don't think it's a problem for most people.

Comment: It's one more not all too compelling reason, IMO.

Comment: when you click, the arrow looks like highlighted and ready to vote at release, but if you scroll before releasing, the vote should not appear. It takes time to master this though

Comment: I am not clicking, I am touching the screen(sometimes accidentally)

Answer (score 9):

Removing the vote lock is a **terrible** solution to this problem. The two are completely unrelated to each other. Better solutions:

1. Find a way to make sure votes don't get cast accidentally. (I don't know anything about mobile click/touch events.)
2. Don't attempt to scroll the page over the vote arrows. I may have only used mobile a few times, but the vote arrows are all the way over on the left. The natural placement of my finger doesn't get me anywhere near the vote arrows when I'm scrolling the page.

Comment: Any excuse for removing the terrible vote lock is a good one :P

Comment: "don't attempt to scroll the page over the vote arrows" is a workaround for those, who are aware about the issue, but doesn't help for them who would do it accidentally and will not noticed. Removing the vote lock is not a solution, but minimizing impact of the problem.

Comment: The vote lock is a terrible solution. It causes many problem, including this one.