# Pros and Cons of locking in up-votes / down-votes on Answers

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, up-votes, locked-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the justification for locking votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70853/what-is-the-justification-for-locking-votes)

What are the pros and cons of locking in votes (that is, up-voting and down-voting an answer)...
On StackOverflow a user answered my programming question correctly but at first I had misread his answer and gave it a down-vote... after re-reading it almost immediately I realized what he meant and it was actually quite brilliant. I went to accept the answer (this worked) and then up-vote the answer (or at least undo my down-vote) but it said "You last voted on this answer 1 minute ago... your vote is now locked until the user edits their answer"... To me this doesn't seem very wise, and I can't think of any benefits of this.

What are the pros and cons of **PERMANENTLY** locking in votes?

Comment: [Tactical Downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22771/the-answer-to-tactical-downvoting-problem)

Comment: ^Perhaps somebody who has NOT answered the question (or maybe even just the asker of the question) should be able to reverse their votes no matter what.

Comment: Consider this scenario, suppose I like what one user is doing and I follow his answers upvoting them.  Then one day months later I don't like him and retract those upvotes, all of them.  It doesn't hurt me, my rep is unaffected.  His rep suddenly drops by a lot due to this.  Is that fair?  This would be similar to the "rage-quitting" phenomenon.

Comment: Could you not do this anyways? Could I not go to your profile and find every answer you've ever given and down vote it? (I really don't know, this is a legitimate question)

Comment: Though you could do that, it would only last for a few hours. The software running the site has code which detects suspicious voting activity - `serial downvoting` is reversed automatically.

Comment: Very fascinating! Thankyou for the serial down voting reference... Would this not then apply to Jeff's example too... therefor allowing us to unlock reverse voting?