# Allow users one late vote change per day

Tags: feature-request, voting, locked-votes

> This is not a duplicate of  [What is the justification for locking votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70853/what-is-the-justification-for-locking-votes).  It  doesn't address the suggestion brought up here to allow a certain limited quota of "unvotes" per week.

It happens rarely, but sometimes new information comes to light on posts I have voted on that make me want to change my vote - for example, a comment may provide new information, or may bring up a different perspective I hadn't considered.

Currently, I can not change my vote after a certain period of time, after which it is "locked in". The only way to change a vote once it is locked in is by editing the post.

That's a harmful workaround, as it bumps the question to the top. Also it's an unfair workaround in that users without editing privileges can't apply it.

Users should be allowed to **change one locked-in vote per day**.

This should account for most erroneous votes, while still preventing [the possible misuse that is the reason why the lock exists in the first place.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70853/what-is-the-justification-for-locking-votes)

Comment: The reason for the lock in is to avoid gaming the system let me see if I can find a link

Comment: I want to note that I posted this specifically at gamedev where I could not find a similar question (a smaller community). I didn't think of it as a feature required generally for any stackexchange site. It is suitable for gamedev imho cause implementation can be sometimes very complex and also the results are of somewhat of an artistic nature at times so further time to think things over may be very useful at times.

Comment: Implementations can be complex on Stack Overflow too so I don't see a reason to make a distinction.

Comment: Ok, I can't find it (grumble grumble) so in short: downvotes are really gameable; downvote everything to make yours rank higher then remkve your votes and the evidence. Upvotes are harder to game but still nkt impossible

Comment: @Louis Well, although both may be complex, you can often simply run the code on some relevant input (in general dev). With game development, you may not have the needed base code to run this scenario. Also, the results are not always of a true or false nature and often can vary on very subtle (artistic) aspects. I don't think I can convince you otherwise if you aren't familiar with gamedev intimately, it is an opinion and not a fact.

Comment: It's worth noting that the vast majority of the software that runs stack exchange is the same for all sites. If you wanted to propose something purely for game dev you'd need an extraordinarily good argument

Comment: @RichardTingle I don't understand how gamedev stackexchange downvote gaming works but I think if you simply put a quota on how many downvotes you can unmake in a day beyond a reasonable amount of time (lets say 1), it could work and prove useful.

Comment: I agree with this. A really tight limit, like the suggested 1 a day, should suffice for most all cases, and it's hard to see how it could be used to game the system.

Comment: Simple solution: Upvote only if you took the time to validate it. No need to rush.

Comment: @gnat No, I am not questioning locking votes and again I had intention to post it here. I am questioning the 20 minutes time limit.

Comment: @juergend I think you did not read the question? I said I have a finite time to consider an answer (I have other things going on) and after some (finite) time I may reach the wrong conclusion, statistics show humans err. If I realize I made a mistake, I don't see why I should be forbade from removing my upvote.

Comment: @Pëkka I'm not seeing how the gaming problem would be prevented with a 1 day delay. I believe the gaming issue happens much faster than 1 day.

Comment: @Louis no, I mean limit the number of possible late vote changes to 1 a day. Or 1 a week.

Comment: And again in case someone missed this, I posted it in gamedev which I am familiar with. I am not familiar with how people game votes in other stackexchanges but I think it is perfectly reasonable to be allowed to remove one upvote (late) in a day. People even have the morning after pill. I don't see how one click should remain permanent when it comes to your opinion of the quality of an answer.

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite: At some point you implement the answer. You can upvote then and not before. And if your time is so precious that you can't take the time to check an answer before upvoting - why do you bother so much that you would take the time to remove an upvote?

Comment: @Pëkka Sorry. I skipped over "a" in "the suggested 1 a day" and we've got a proposal here to expand the delay to a day, which with "the suggested" (which I understand *now* is in the comments, not in the question), tripped me up.

Comment: I don't see the fundamental differences between gamedev.SE and the rest of the network in this issue. (But as said I agree the system should be changed.)

Comment: @juergend Why do you care enough to post comments? Each of us want to express their opinion clearly and share our knowledge. I don't see how why do you care is an answer / reason to forbid something simple.

Comment: @juergen so you *never* have the desire to change a vote, say when receiving new information (like in a comment) or seeing a different viewpoint that changes your mind? Never ever?

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite: It's your argument I don't get. You say: *I don't have time to upvote later after verifying, but I would make time to remove a vote*.

Comment: @Pëkka: If there would be such a case that I can't stand that a user got 10 rep from my upvote, I would edit the post and remove the vote. But is it really that terrible not to remove it?

Comment: @juergend Why does something have to be terrible in order for it to be changed? That is like saying is that splinter really detrimental to your health that you need to remove it? Why can't something be changed only so it will be more convenient? Are SSD really needed when we have magnetic drives? Is it really terrible to continue using magnetic drives? Why are people still willing to pay extra for SSD when magnetic drives are widely available? Convenience is also important. Something doesn't have to be terrible for it be improved especially with UX.

Comment: @juergend I did say I take time to think about it. I said it's a finite amount of time. If I happen to think about it some more, removing an upvote only takes a few seconds. I don't see how saying that I have finite time to check the answer cancels out the possibility that I also have additional (finite time) to correct my vote if I find it is incorrect?

Comment: @juergen but don't you agree that having to edit the post just to change your vote is a horrible workaround? It needlessly bumps the question, for one. And what if the vote I want to remove is a downvote? An erroneous downvote can sting a lot, and yes I occasionally have found myself wanting to remove one.

Comment: I read the answers in the "duplicate" question. First this is not a duplicate. I am referring very specifically to have a quota of (1 per day) chances to change (specifically) an upvote made that day. I don't see why it is being attacked but I lose interest, if people think it's terrible to be able to improve your idea about something perhaps I should respect that.

Comment: @Pëkka: I agree with that.

Comment: Downvotes are used on Meta to express disagreement with a suggestion, not necessarily to attack it because of quality and such

Comment: I'll try to edit the suggestion to make it clearer what you are getting at - feel free to roll back if you disagree.

Comment: @Pëkka Yes, you're correct. Is the edit I made not showing? I may have not initially referred to that but I did correct it immediately cause that is suitable to the situation I wish to improve. I did state that I simply wanted some extra time to be able to reconsider and do not mind the lock-down that much but fill it is way too tight. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Comment: I edited it. It's a radical edit, check it out and change it if you don't like it - it's your question. But I think it now gets down to the meat of the suggestion, which was a bit obscured in the previous version. The premise that votes can be snap decisions applies on Meta, too ;)

Comment: People, this is *not* a duplicate. @gnat et al, please vote to reopen.

Comment: It looks good. I think the essence is there.

Comment: @Pëkka per my reading, [revs 3 through 6](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/226308/revisions) clearly de-duped this question (voted reopen)

Comment: @gnat yeah, it was a dupe initially, you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I don't see a particular need for this feature.

If you are looking at an answer you cannot immediately judge is worthy of an up or down vote, rather than *guessing* and coming back later to verify you should just abstain. If you cannot afford to invest the time into researching the veracity of an answer *now*, but intend to do so *later* (and potentially change your vote, per your feature request), then you should just *wait until later to vote*.

If you accidentally upvote a bad answer (or downvote a good one) and it gets locked in, the community will in most cases correct it in the long run.

EDIT, based on some commentary discussion: I am primarily opposed to this feature because I think it allows more cavalier voting (even if only slightly, due to the proposed throttle), and it is *my opinion* that such behavior shouldn't be encouraged. I believe votes are an important part of the network, and also that new features should help guide users towards correct, beneficial use of the site whenever possible.

Comment: so you never have the desire to change a vote, say when receiving new information (like in a comment) or seeing a different viewpoint that changes your mind? Never ever? I don't believe that. Re "the community will correct it" - that's true, but a downvote carries great significance to many SO users, and wanting to remove it if it turns out to be unjustified can be of some importance. Add to that that high-rep users can *already* work around the restriction by editing the post - which is unfair and harmful, as the question gets bumped for no reason. Fixing this would be a small change.

Comment: Of course I have, but *extremely* rarely. I am generally very careful with my votes. In the few occasions I can ever remember wanting to, it wasn't a big deal because the aggregate vote had already gone strongly in the same direction. This just isn't a feature that seems worth the engineering effort, in my opinion. (On the subject of high-rep users introducing an edit to change their vote, I don't think that's proper use of the edit feature and I'd argue that high-rep users should know better; but I realize that's perhaps overly idealistic of me, especially on larger sites).

Comment: We don't know whether there is any engineering effort in this at all. For all we know, it could be a change in a configuration setting.

Comment: That's true, but that argument goes both ways. You can't say "fixing this would be a small change" either (unless you *do* know things about the back-end implementation; I certainly don't).

Comment: That's true, we don't know either way. (Re high-rep users [ab]using the edit feature - it's pretty common and accepted practice. And understandably so, in my opinion.)

Comment: I too rarely wanted to un-upvote (maybe twice) and even more seldom (once) had to revert a commit I made in git but although I could have done it manually, it was nice and convenient that it could be done with one simple command. If it happened to you rarely, it possibly happened to each of us rarely so multiply that by the number of users.

Comment: *Fundamentally* I am opposed to a feature that allows (if slightly, due to the proposed throttle) users to be more cavalier with their votes, since votes are an important part of the SE network and should be considered carefully, in my opinion.

Comment: But it is precisely the opposite that I am hoping for. I realize I sometimes make mistakes with my votes (not often). Perhaps 1/100? Maybe less, mayhap more. If I do make a mistake I wish to correct it. User that are cavalier with their votes will likely continue to be. They do not care to correct one mistake per day or per week. This feature will likely only be used by people who consider their vote meaningful if not to themselves than to others.

Comment: Yes, that kind of mistake happens, and that's why we have a community so that aggregate votes trend in the proper direction and one user can't skew the whole system by making a completely understandable mis-call once in a while.

Comment: Yes and I am sure it works if questions get lots of attention but that is not really the case in GDSE. we have more of a long tail. I don't think questions always get plenty of attention. An upvote on a question that looks promising (although it's incorrect) may deter users from participating and offering their alternative and possibly correct solutions. It is often the easy or opinion based questions that get "love" from the users and it is often not correcting the situation but instead creating a problem.

Comment: I have absolutely no confidence that this feature would improve user engagement on GDSE. The engagement issues on that site are far broader; users who are deterred from posting an alternative to answer based on a *single vote* on another answer are a deeper issue. Even if they would suddenly convert, en masse, and post answers when that one vote was reversed, that's still fixing a *symptom* and not a *cause*.