# Change vote after time limit has been exceeded

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vote too old to be changed, unless post is edited “problem”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited-problem)

I made a downvote on an answer because I felt that the answer was outside the scope of the question, but after a few comments, my opinion was changed.
I would like to retract my downvote, but I can't because it says that the answer must be edited.

Is there a way to change my vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, make a (suggested) edit, or post a comment wherein you ask the answerer to make a minor edit so that you can remove the downvote.